# Blank Product Data in Magento custom product_list block

Tags: php, xml, magento

Been stumbling me for over an hour now and that means time to ask for help! I have a custom block in my Magento theme to show 4 products from a category - this being Best Seller's. The block is showing the 4 products and has the correct link, however, none of the other details seem to be loading, such as: Name, Price, Image and Rating etc... Very strange!

Here is my XML which is located in the Design for CMS Index:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="tabs.products.best" as="bestSellers" template="page/html/home/best-sellers.phtml">
        <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
        <action method="setLimit"><limit>4</limit></action>
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>product_list_toolbar</alias></action>
    <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>64</category_id></action>
</block>
```

This uses this function in the template file:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->setPageSize(4)
    ->load();

$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: To make things shorter you can use `$_productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();` instead. It does essentially the same work but with less effort to you. This doesn't negate Jim's reasonable answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this before the ->load() to load the default attribute set:

```
->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
```

The default attribute set should include all of the fields you mention above (and a whole lot more).